# Karate - Having multiple 'When's in single scenario

Tags: cucumber, karate

I have a scenario where there are multiple steps/ REST operations needs to be run to complete one process.

Each REST operation needs to have authorization username and password. I have provided this in **Background** session. This is how my present feature looks like.

```
Feature: Adding to cart

  Background: 
    * url 'https://soa-mp-rmsk-someurl.com'
    * header agent_uid = 'AUTO_TST'
    * configure ssl = true
    * header Authorization = call read('classpath:Project/JSFiles/auth.js') { username: 'ABC', password: '123' }
    * configure logPrettyResponse = true
    * configure logPrettyRequest = true

  Scenario: Find available mobiles
    Given path '/v1/available-mobiles'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    * def mobile = response.iPhoneXSMax

  # Add a mobile to cart
    Given path '/v1/mobiles/'+mobile+'/add
    And request {name: 'iPhoneXSMax'}
    When method put
    Then status 200
```

Now this throws error saying that `"faultstring": "Authentication challenge issued"`.

I can group them into different scenarios so that they call `header authorization` every time which results in successful run; I have tried this as well. Works for me. But i don't think its a good practice to group these steps in different scenarios as they literally makes a single scenario. How can i overcome this error? Or should i go and distribute them in different scenarios?

https://automationpanda.com/2018/02/03/are-gherkin-scenarios-with-multiple-when-then-pairs-okay/

**EDIT-1**
This is how i tried to add configure headers for Authorization details; I was not able to fully understand this, could you please help?

**headers.js**

```
function fn() {
      var username = karate.get('username');
      var password = karate.get('password');
      if (username && password) {
        return { 
            Authorization: username + password
        };
      } else {
        return {};
      }
    }
```

And i called it in feature background like this; but didn't worked.

```
* configure headers = read('classpath:headers.js')
* def username = 'ABC'
* def password = '123'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have completely missed that for header based auth - Karate has a global kind of a hook - which is what most teams use. Refer the docs for [`configure headers`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure-headers).

Comment: Thanks Peter; I went though it and also this. [https://www.testingexcellence.com/set-multiple-headers-http-request-karate/] But, how can i add authorization details to `configure headers`? And also i need to call '* configure headers' everytime before a new `Given` statement starts right? Or, if I call once in background is sufficient? (Which is okay for me)

Comment: @sandeephegde the example in the documentation and demos is all about authorization. read it and then ask specific questions. and yes call in the background - but there are other ways which I will leave as homework for you - search for "hooks" in the docs.

Comment: I did some work and added auth details like i mentioned in question. But i think i need to convert/encode username and password to Base64 format. Could you please help me with the `headers.js` file?

Comment: I guess i need to ask a different question :)

Comment: @sandeephegde no. you need to actually READ the docs. take a day off and do it. it will be worth it.

Comment: Thank you, I manage to fix this one. Have provided the solution below as well. Please let me know if i need to know anything else.

Comment: I know this question is old, but I believe this answer doesn't exactly answer the question, nor does the linked documentation. The question is about having to call headers in each call when multiple calls are inside the same scenario. OP's question is about auth, but for me it's about having a lot of headers and not wanting to set them in each call - why doesn't background apply each time the 'Given' keyword is used, even if in the same scenario?

Comment: @Anakin001 it should. so what you are reporting sounds like a bug. follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue -  otherwise we can spend weeks debating whether the documents or your understanding is right - and a reminder, use `configure` not anything else.

Comment: That actually answers the question I would say :) Both me and OP were using individual 'header' keywords, which seems to only apply once, at the beginning of each scenario. After moving my (long) list of headers to a dedicated file and calling configure headers = read('file') the headers are now updated before each 'Given' statement. Not sure if it's a bug or not, but using configure solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Anakin001 that's great. not a bug :) and the answer above - although short, contains the critical words (and link to): `configure headers`.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to say that for the **EDIT-1** i managed to get the solution. This is how i have written my headers.js file which has BASE64 format conversion.

Please let me know guys, if i can enhance it in any better way.

```
function fn() {
      var username = karate.get('username');
      var password = karate.get('password');

      if (username && password) {
      var temp = username + ':' + password;
      var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
      var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(temp.bytes)
        return { 
            Authorization: 'Basic ' + encoded
        };
      } else {
        return {};
      }
    }
```